# The word "moody"

Tags: word-meaning

Could you please tell me what it means when English speakers say that someone is *moody*? Which meaning is more common? Does context play role? Does the frequency of using this or that meaning depend on the area you live (UK, USA, etc.)?

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moody), this word has at least two quite different meanings.

Comment: It usually means "in a bad mood".  If it can't mean that, then it means "frequently has bad moods".

Comment: It seems that it may be area-dependent. British online dictionaries give 'liable to frequent changes of mood' as the primary definition, while Merriam-Webster gives 'subject to depression; gloomy'. (All of them give both meanings.)

Comment: It would differ from context-to-context. It would be better if you could provide the sentence where you are looking for this word.

Comment: Comparing the relative prevalence of the collocations ***moody and depressed*** and ***moody and irritable*** on [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moody+and+depressed%2Cmoody+and+irritable&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmoody%20and%20depressed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoody%20and%20irritable%3B%2Cc0) for both AmE and BrE corpuses, I don't see much difference. This suggests to me that both "flavours" of ***moody*** are equally familiar on both sides of the pond (there's no significant "regional variation").

Answer (score 1):

Speaking for USA, it often means the person is in a bad mood, or prone to bad moods, but out of politeness or fear you don't want to say directly they are in a bad mood (a common substitution used towards one's spouse).

It can also refer to a depressed mood.  Example:

"Ever since John became a teenager, he has been moody.  Happy one minute, crying the next."

Note this does sound like Kate's example of "liable to frequent changes of mood."  The important point is it never has a purely positive connotation.

An example you would **never** see:

"Sally is so moody.  Excited one minute, calmly happy the next."

I would suggest that context does *not* play a big role in the meaning of this word.  It's always a complaint.  In the rare case you wanted to point out to someone that they were in a happy mood when recently they were in a bad mood, you might say:

"You're having mood swings."

"Mood swings" has a very similar meaning, but with a hint towards a history of clinical mental instability.